# Steht das Präpositionalobjekt von »färben« im Akkusativ oder im Dativ?

Tags: word-usage, preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

- > Ich färbe den Stoff in helles Rot und dunkles Orange.

  oder

  > Ich färbe den Stoff in hellem Rot und dunklem Orange.
- > Ich färbe den Stoff in alle Schattierungen von Rot

  oder

  > Ich färbe den Stoff in allen Schattierungen von Rot
- > Gott färbt die Welt in graue Hoffnungslosigkeit und düstere Verzweiflung

  oder

  > Gott färbt die Welt in grauer Hoffnungslosigkeit und düsterer Verzweiflung

Wo kann ich nachschlagen, ob in diesen Fällen Dativ oder Akkusativ verwendet werden soll?

Comment: Es ist kein Präpositional-*Objekt,* sondern eine schlichte Adverbiale der Art und Weise.

Answer (score 3):

Hier bezieht sich der Akkusativ auf den Zustand des Objekts, während der Dativ die Umstände der Handlung beschreibt.

Am deutlichsten ist der Unterschied im dritten Beispiel:

> Gott färbt die Welt in graue Hoffnungslosigkeit und düstere Verzweiflung.

Die Welt verändert sich.

> Gott färbt die Welt in grauer Hoffnungslosigkeit und düsterer Verzweiflung.

Gott ist verzweifelt.

Was das Beispiel aus der Überschrift betrifft, wäre demnach "in helles Rot färben" präziser, "in hellem Rot färben" aber nicht falsch, da die Begriffe nicht sehr viel Spielraum lassen.